# Identifier not loaded in c

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to run a example on handling signals, and it fails compiling on a unfound identifier.

Here is how the header is loaded :

```
#define __USE_GNU
#include <ucontext.h>
```

And the error when compiling (with gcc):

```
$ gcc -o sa_siginfo sa_siginfo.c
sa_siginfo.c: In function ‘bt_sighandler’:
sa_siginfo.c:25:28: error: ‘REG_RIP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      uc->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]);
```

GCC info:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
```

/usr/include/ucontext.h does include /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h which has:

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
[...]
#ifdef __USE_GNU
/* Number of each register in the `gregset_t' array.  */
enum
{
  [...]
  REG_RIP,
```

(My system is 64 bits)

So I don't understand why it doesn't find it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve REG\_EIP undeclared (First use in this function ) error on Linux 32 bit machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679267/how-to-resolve-reg-eip-undeclared-first-use-in-this-function-error-on-linux-3)

Comment: Nope I already checked that one

Comment: Try only doing the preprocessor step of compilation (by giving the right command line switch) and check the output for clues.

Comment: Also adding the failing compile command, as well as compiler version, to the question might help getting an answer.

Comment: I didn't include that because it is fairly standard, but I just added these.

Comment: You could try adding [`-std=gnu99`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) (default is `gnu90`). Also check that `CFLAGS` environment variable is not set with some unexpected flags.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling your program like this

```
gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -o sa_siginfo sa_siginfo.c
```

That `__USE_GNU` is defined only if you defined `_GNU_SOURCE`, and `gcc` will not define it by default.

Comment: I tried but it seem it was already defined as I get : warning: "__USE_GNU" redefined

Comment: You should remove that `#define __USE_GNU` in your source code.